# Optimize Prepared statement Query

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I am trying to pull data out of my database for a search. I tried to use a join but the results take 40 seconds to display. I also tried splitting my query up into two, which also does not work due to problems with nested prepared statements. How can I optimize the join query? Am I correct in splitting the query up to speed the process up? If so why is my nested loop not working?

Query with join-

```
SELECT pdf.pdf_ID
     , pdf.absolute_path
     , sentance.sen_value
     , sentance.pdf_ID 
  FROM pdf 
  JOIN sentance 
    ON sentance.pdf_ID = pdf.pdf_ID 
 WHERE pdf.absolute_path LIKE ? 
   AND sentance.sen_value LIKE ? 
 LIMIT ?,?
```

Split queries-

part 1-

```
SELECT pdf.absolute_path
     , pdf.pdf_ID 
  FROM pdf 
 WHERE pdf.absolute_path like "Data|Digital%" 
 ORDER 
    BY pdf.pdf_ID
```

part 2-

```
SELECT sentance.sen_value 
  FROM sentance 
 WHERE sentance.pdf_ID = 24159 
   and sentance.sen_value like "%John%" 
 LIMIT ?,?
```

PHP with split queries not working due to prepared statement.

```
  function getQueryResultCategory($pageNumber,$itemsPerPage,$word,$path){

$pdfIDList=array();


//$query="Select pdf.pdf_ID, pdf.absolute_path, sentance.pdf_ID, sentance.sen_value from pdf INNER JOIN sentance ON sentance.pdf_ID = pdf.pdf_ID WHERE sentance.sen_value LIKE ? LIMIT ?,? ODER BY pdf.pdf_ID";



//if we break this query into two parts
$getPDFsQuery="
SELECT absolute_path 
     , pdf_ID 
  FROM pdf 
 WHERE absolute_path LIKE ? 
 Order 
    BY pdf_ID";

$getResults="
SELECT sen_value 
  FROM sentance 
 WHERE pdf_ID = ? 
   and sen_value LIKE ? 
 LIMIT ?,?";



$searchTerm = "%".$word."%";
$path = $path."%";


$page_position = (($pageNumber-1) * $itemsPerPage);
include('Resources/Connections/localHost.php');
  if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)){
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      mysqli_close($con);
}else if($partOne = $con->prepare($getPDFsQuery) or die(mysqli_error($con))){
     $partOne->bind_param('s', $path);
     $partOne->execute();
     $partOne->store_result();
     $partOne->bind_result($pathski,$pdfID);
     if($partOne->num_rows < 1){
       echo "no Results found in category ".$pathski;

       mysqli_close($con);

       $partOne->close();
       //now that we have the pdf ids where the path matches we need to search these for the phrase
     }else{

       //put the pdf paths into an array so I can go through them and call queries on them
       while($partOne-> fetch()){
         echo "PDF File: ".$pathski."<br />";
         echo $getResults."<br />";
         echo $pdfID."<br />";
         echo $searchTerm."<br />";
         echo $page_position."<br />";
         echo $itemsPerPage."<br />";


         //we need to execute a query for each of the PDFs that match the category. AKA run that pdf id through aniother query.
         if($partTwo = $con->prepare($getResults) or die(mysqli_error($con))){
           $partTwo->bind_param('isii', $pdfID,$searchTerm,$page_position,$itemsPerPage);
           $partTwo->execute();
           $partTwo->store_result();
           $partTwo->bind_result($sentance);
           if($partTwo->num_rows < 1){
             echo "no search term found in PDF".$pathski."<br />";

             mysqli_close($con);

             $partTwo->close();
             //now that we have the pdf ids where the path matches we need to search these for the phrase
           }else{



             /*
             while($partTwo->fetch()){



               $occuranceCount;
               $pathStack = array();
               $current;

                $current=$pdfID;
                if(end($pathStack)!=$current){
                  $occuranceCount=0;
                  $current="";
                  $current=$pdfID;
                  array_push($pathStack,$current);
                }else{
                  array_push($pathStack,$current);
                  $occuranceCount++;
                }

                $pathski= str_replace('|','/',$pathski);


                $pathski= str_replace(' ','_',$pathski);


                    //we need to get the word from the sentance and wrap it in a sapn
                    $startPOS;
                    if(preg_match ('/'.$word.'/i', $sentance, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)){
                      $indexOpen = $matches[0][1];
                    }
                    //need to add logic if search word is first word in sentance add span to beginning of sentance
                    $openTagPOS=$indexOpen;
                    if($openTagPOS<=0){
                      $openTagPOS=0;
                      $sentance = substr_replace($sentance, "<span class='highlight'>", $openTagPOS, 0);
                      if(preg_match ('/'.$word.'/i', $sentance, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)){
                        $indexClose = $matches[0][1];
                        $indexClose=strlen($word)+$indexClose;
                        $sentance = substr_replace($sentance, "</span>", $indexClose, 0);
                      }
                    }else{
                      $sentance = substr_replace($sentance, "<span class='highlight'>", $openTagPOS, 0);
                      if(preg_match ('/'.$word.'/i', $sentance, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)){
                        $indexClose = $matches[0][1];
                      }
                      $closingTagPOS=$indexClose+strlen($word);
                      $sentance = substr_replace($sentance, "</span>", $closingTagPOS, 0);
                    }

                    echo "<div class='result'>";



                    if(isset($_SESSION['browser']) && $_SESSION['browser']=="Chrome"){

                        echo "<p class ='path'>File: <a href='http://www.digifind-it.com/Parkway/pdfJS/pdfViewer/web/viewer.html?file=../../../".$pathski."&search=".$word."&occurance=".$occuranceCount."' target='blank'>".basename($pathski)."</a></p>";

                    }else if(isset($_SESSION['browser']) && $_SESSION['browser']!="Chrome"){

                        echo "<p class ='path'>File: <a href='http://www.digifind-it.com/Parkway/".$pathski."#search=\"".$word."\"' target='blank'>".basename($pathski)."</a></p>";


                    }
                      echo "<p class ='context'> context: ".$sentance."</p><br>";
                      echo "<p class ='context'> occurance num: ".$occuranceCount."</p><br>";
                      echo"</div>";

                     }
                     */


         }
      }
    }
    echo "<div align='center'>";
    echo paginate_function($itemsPerPage, $_SESSION['pagenumber']);
    echo "</div>";
  }
}
```

}

In the PHP $partTwo gives an error. Could not prepare statement.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Sentence and PDF tables are both indexed on pdf_ID.

Your main issue, though, is the LIKE in the WHERE clause.  Those don't perform well, especially if there's a wild-card character at the start.

Comment: What is the reason for the down-vote?  It properly answers the original poster's question "How can I optimize the join query?"

Comment: I did not down vote this. I just upvoted it to make it 0. So you're saying the primary key in the sentence table needs to be pdf_ID? Shouldn't I set up a unique primary key like sen_ID then use pdf_ID as a foreign key?

Comment: @TimHunt, I have no idea who cast the down-vote - my question was "to whom it may concern" :)  I didn't mean that the primary key on the Sentence table needs to be pdf_ID, but the Sentence table should have an index on that column; it will improve join performance.  Making it a foreign key into the PDF table may be a good idea, too, if all Sentence records have to belong to a PDF record.